# c# - html "nested table" in class

Tags: c#, html

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadString("a web link");
```

and i am getting an HTML page in which there's a table like this

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td> Team 1 ID </td>
   <td> Team 1 Name </td>
   <td>
       <table>
        <tr>
           <td> Member 1 name </td>
           <td> Member 1 age </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td> Member 2 name </td>
           <td> Member 2 age </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> Team 2 ID </td>
   <td> Team 2 Name </td>
   <td>
       <table>
        <tr>
           <td> Member 1 name </td>
           <td> Member 1 age </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

that means another table in each row of main table so i called it nested table. 
whatever, now i want to get these data into class like this

```
class Team
{

    public int teamID;
    public string teamName;
    public struct Member
    {
        public string memberName;
        public int memberAge;
    }

    public Member member1;
    public Member member2;
}
```

note that, each team might have 0 to 3 members

so i am seeking for a sound solution that can solve my problem. 
should i use RegEx or HtmlAgilityPack or which way is appropriate and how?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use HtmlAgilityPack. If you run into any troubles, I can help you.

> Regular expressions can only match regular languages but HTML is a
>   context-free language. The only thing you can do with regexps on HTML
>   is heuristics but that will not work on every condition. It should be
>   possible to present a HTML file that will be matched wrongly by any
>   regular expression.

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

It will be easier if your html contains any identifiers (css classes or id)

Updated code: Here is my suggestion to approach your problem

```
        string mainURL = "your url";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(mainURL);

        var tables = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Where(_ => _.Descendants("table").Any());//this will give you all tables which contain another table inside
        foreach (var table in tables)
        {
            var rows = table.ChildNodes.Where(_ => _.Name.Equals("tr"));//get all tr children (not grand children)
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (row.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("td"))
                    {
                        //you can put your logic here, for eg i == 0, assign it to TeamID properties etc...
                    }
                    if (row.ChildNodes[i].Name.Equals("table"))
                    {
                        //here is your logic to handle nested table
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: each table has same class so can't identify separately. 
okay i am trying but it will be great if you give me some code solution for this problem.

Comment: Just provide your html with all available attributes, I can point you to the right direction

Comment: <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Class ID</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Time</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>00001</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>
             <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
              <tr>
               <td>8:00 AM </td> 
               <td>9:30 AM </td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>8:00 AM </td> 
               <td>9:30 AM </td> 
              </tr>
             </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

Comment: this is the actual table structure. original table has 1600/+ row and another table in each row!  due to authentication issue, i can't give you page link :/

Comment: sorry to say but this code is not working. though its going through all the <td> , i have checked using counter but not getting proper data in my class.

Comment: problem might be somewhere else like as i am using webclient.DownloadString("mylink") so i found that it is also getting \r  . \n and lots of spaces. so i am getting null value in class  properties!! what can i do now? pls help. i guess we are close enough

Comment: update: but if i use i==1, i==3 that means i == odd , then i am getting it right!!

Comment: you can use `node.GetAttributeValue("class","")` to get value of class attr, it will return empty in case there is no class attr.